# Не отображается меню «Автор» в записи

Tags: wordpress

При создании записи в supports проставил author,но само меню не отображается...почему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для поля автор нет метабокса с полями для редактирования. В него записывается текущий пользователь. Так же данный пользователь должен быть создан на сайте. Если вы хотите изменять автора страницы вам необходимо сделать метабокс, а затем на хук `save_post` или `wp_insert_post` обновлять его.